# Where do you get FontDescriptor information for the 14 REQUIRED fonts for PDF files?

Tags: pdf

Where do you get FontDescriptor information for the 14 REQUIRED fonts for PDF files?

I can find only for Helvetica Normal.
The 13 others must be available from somewhere, but from where?

This information must be avialable for other fonts as well, as PDF Reference 1.7 provides partial info for the Garamond font.

Complete FontDescriptor for Helvetica font (from pdf 2.0)

```
7 0 obj
<<
  /Type /Font
  /Subtype /Type1
  /BaseFont /Helvetica
  /FirstChar 33
  /LastChar 126
  /Widths 8 0 R
  /FontDescriptor 9 0 R
>>
endobj

8 0 obj
[ 278 355 556 556 889 667 222 333 333 389 584 278 333 278 278 556
  556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 556 278 278 584 584 584 556 1015
  667 667 722 722 667 611 778 722 278 500 667 556 833 722 778 667
  778 722 667 611 722 667 944 667 667 611 278 278 278 469 556 222
  556 556 500 556 556 278 556 556 222 222 500 222 833 556 556 556
  556 333 500 278 556 500 722 500 500 500 334 260 334 584 ]
endobj

% This FontDescriptor contains only the required entries for PDF 2.0
% for unembedded standard 14 fonts that contain Latin characters
9 0 obj
<<
  /Type /FontDescriptor
  /FontName /Helvetica
  /Flags 32
  /FontBBox [ -166 -225 1000 931 ]
  /ItalicAngle 0
  /Ascent 718
  /Descent -207
  /CapHeight 718
  /StemV 88
  /MissingWidth 0  
>>
endobj
```

Partial FontDescriptor for Garamond font (from pdf 1.7)

```
14 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /AGaramond−Semibold
/FirstChar 0
/LastChar 255
/Widths 21 0 R
/FontDescriptor 7 0 R
/Encoding 25 0 R
>>
endobj
21 0 obj
[ 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 280 438 510 510 868 834 248 320 320 420 510 255 320 255 347
510 510 510 510 510 510 510 510 510 510 255 255 510 510 510 330
781 627 627 694 784 580 533 743 812 354 354 684 560 921 780 792
588 792 656 504 682 744 650 968 648 590 638 320 329 320 510 500
380 420 510 400 513 409 301 464 522 268 259 484 258 798 533 492
516 503 349 346 321 520 434 684 439 448 390 320 255 320 510 255
627 627 694 580 780 792 744 420 420 420 420 420 420 402 409 409
409 409 268 268 268 268 533 492 492 492 492 492 520 520 520 520
486 400 510 510 506 398 520 555 800 800 1044 360 380 549 846 792
713 510 549 549 510 522 494 713 823 549 274 354 387 768 615 496
330 280 510 549 510 549 612 421 421 1000 255 627 627 792 1016 730
500 1000 438 438 248 248 510 494 448 590 100 510 256 256 539 539
486 255 248 438 1174 627 580 627 580 580 354 354 354 354 792 792
790 792 744 744 744 268 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380
]
endobj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AFM "font metrics" files are widely available. e.g:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/opentype/tech-notes/Core14_AFMs.zip

Here's the format spec:

https://adobe-type-tools.github.io/font-tech-notes/pdfs/5004.AFM_Spec.pdf

For Type 1 fonts, the AFM information is usually in the .pfm file.

If you want to embed your own TrueType fonts, you'll have to extract the metrics from within the font file itself, in order to fill out the PDF font metadata.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need.----The link to the zip file is broken, but I should be able to find elsewhere, as I now know what to look for.----THANKS!@johnwhitington